# how to add a new key in Android device

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I have a device with Tao3530chip and there is a Android 2.3.3 system on it. I'm also having a button at gpio100 on that Tao chip. I'd like to use that button to perform some control in the high level application.

If I map this gpio 100 to a certain key value in the .kl file, lets say KEY_ESC which has the value 1, what I need more is to change the high level response to this key event.

However, obviously its not a good mapping.

On the other hand, I dont know how to map my gpio100 to an unused or user-defined key value in the .kl file. I understanding is that maybe i need to perform the following:

```
#define KEY_MYDEFINE 0x123
```

(0x123 is an unused value.)
And map my gpio100 to KEY_MYDEFINE. And then later code the high level response for KEY_MYDEFINE. Is the procedure correct?

Comment: run **getevent** on the cmd-line console of your android device and press the gpio key. Observe the value that is logged to the cmdline console by getevent. This value you need to use in the kl file on your device to map the key you want(KEY_ESC for example).